# Finitely generated modules over noetherian rings isomorphic to their double duals

Tags: commutative-algebra, ring-theory, modules

Let $R$ be a noetherian ring and $M$ a finitely generated $R$-module. Suppose that $M$ is isomorphic to the double dual, how can I prove that $M$ is reflexive? (i.e. it is isomorphic to the double dual through the canonical map).

Comment: By the canonical map you mean the map $f\mapsto \mbox{ev}_f$, where $\mbox{ev}_f(\lambda) = \lambda(f)$?

Comment: yes, the map $m\mapsto(\varphi\mapsto\varphi(m))$

Comment: For noetherian integral domains it seems to be okay, because the dual of any finitely generated module is reflexive. BTW, the posted question can be found [here](http://www.math.ku.edu/~huneke/Vita/Sp04.pdf) as exercise 11, page 38. This makes a connection with a remark from Mathoverflow where someone said that this result was proved (but not published) by a student of Huneke.

Comment: Since I would like to know how to prove what you stated I posted a question here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/225790/the-dual-of-a-finitely-generated-module-over-a-noetherian-integral-domain-is-ref

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For any module $X$, I will let $\alpha_X:X\rightarrow X^{**}$ be the canonical map you described; for $a\in X, b\in X^*$, $\alpha_X(a)(b)=b(a)$.  I claim that for any $X$, $\alpha_{X^*}:X^*\rightarrow X^{***}$ is a split injection; in fact it is split by the map $\alpha_X^*$ which is dual to $\alpha_X$.  The splitting map is explicitly given by $\alpha_X^*(c)(a)=c(\alpha_X(a))$ for $c\in X^{***}$ and $a\in X$.

To verify this claim, let $a\in X, b\in X^*$.  Then $\alpha_X^*(\alpha_{X^*}(b))(a)=\alpha_{X^*}(b)(\alpha_X(a))=\alpha_X(a)(b)=b(a)$.  Since this holds for all $a$ and $b$, $\alpha_X^*\circ\alpha_{X^*}=\mathrm{id}$ as desired.

Suppose now that $M$ is a noetherian module, and let $f:M\rightarrow M^{**}$ be an isomorphism. Applying the above to $X=M^*$ shows $\alpha_{M^{**}}$ is a split injection.  Using the naturality of $\alpha$ and the fact that $f$ is an isomorphism, it is clear that $\alpha_M$ is a split injection.  We wish to show it is an isomorphism.  Let $\beta:M^{**}\rightarrow M$ be the splitting map.  It suffices to show $\beta$, or equivalently $\beta\circ f$, is injective.

That $\beta \circ f:M\rightarrow M$ is an isomorphism is a special case of the fact that an epimorphism from a noetherian module $M$ to itself is always an isomorphism. To prove this fact, let $\phi$ be such an epimorphism, e.g. $\phi=\beta \circ f$.  Consider the chain of submodules $\ker \phi^n\subseteq M$.  Because $M$ is noetherian there exists n such that $\ker \phi^n=\ker \phi^{n+1}$.  If $x\in \ker \phi$, then $x=\phi^n(y)$ for some $y$.  Since $\phi(x)=0$, $y\in \ker\phi^{n+1}=\ker\phi^n$, so $x=0$. Hence $\phi$ is injective.

Since $\beta\circ f$ is injective, $\alpha_M$ is surjective, which completes the proof.

Comment: wait....I have a question, since every surjective endomorphism of a finitely generated module is an isomorphism (see http://www.math.us.edu.pl/zatl/szymiczek/referaty/NAKsurj.pdf theorem 1 on page 3), it seems to me that we don't have to require the noetherianity of the ring, am I wrong?

Comment: So every finitely generated module isomorphic to the double dual is reflexive? We don't need noetherianity?

Comment: This proof shows that there is no reason to consider the ring $R$ noetherian.