# The dual of a finitely generated module over a noetherian integral domain is reflexive.

Tags: commutative-algebra, ring-theory, modules

As posted by user26857 in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/222530/finitely-generated-modules-over-noetherian-rings-isomorphic-to-their-double-dual) the dual of a finitely generated module over a noetherian integral domain is reflexive. Could you tell me how to prove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have a proof.

I will use this [theorem](http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/SAC/SAC_1966-1967__1_/SAC_1966-1967__1__A1_0/SAC_1966-1967__1__A1_0.pdf):

> Let $A$ be a Noetherian ring and $M$ a finitely generated $A$-module. Then
>   $M^*$ is reflexive if and only if $M^*_P$ is reflexive for every $P$ such that $\mathrm{depth}\;A_P=0$; in short, a dual is reflexive if and only if it is reflexive in depth $0$.

If the ring is a domain then the only prime of depth $0$ is the zero ideal. If $M$ is finitely generated, then $M^*_{(0)}$ is a finite dimensional vector space over the ring of fractions and so it is reflexive.