# Non-reflexive module isomorphic to its double dual

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules

> Could you give me an example of a non-reflexive module isomorphic to its double dual?

I found an example [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/76000/are-there-non-reflexive-modules-isomorphic-to-their-bi-dual) but I cannot understand it, do you have any simpler examples?

By [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/222530/finitely-generated-modules-over-noetherian-rings-isomorphic-to-their-double-dual) we should only use not finitely generated modules.

Comment: In general I hope we don't get a lot of questions of the form "I didn't understand the solution to this other question. Give me easier solutions," but this one in particular seems like it can stand.

Comment: Is the countable direct sum of the ring of natural numbers  $\mathbb Z$ an example? The dual is the countable product.

Comment: @R.C.Cowsik No, the countable direct sum of copies $\mathbb{Z}$ is reflexive as an abelian group. See Specker, E. (1950). Additive gruppen von Folgen ganzer Zahlen. *Portugaliae Mathematica,* 9(3), 131-140. (The desired result is the content of Theorem III.)

Answer (score -2):

What about $l^1(\mathbb{R})$ as an $\mathbb{R}$ vector space?

The natural map $J_1\colon l^\infty \to (l^1)^\vee$, which reads a bounded sequence as the multiplication by said sequence, is an isomorphism, while the dual map $J_2\colon l^1 \to (l^\infty)^\vee$ is not. We then get, composing the natural bidual map with the traspose of $J_1$, that
$$l^1 \to (l^1)^{\vee\vee} \to (l^\infty)^{\vee}$$
is, again, $J_2$! Hence $l^1$ cannot be reflexive. Still, we can find bases of the same cardinality for the two spaces.

Comment: $(\ell^\infty)^\vee$ is not isomorphic to $\ell^1$, even just algebraically (or even as sets--$(\ell^\infty)^\vee$ has strictly greater cardinality!).  In any case, this question is about *algebraic* duals.